# Elsaticsearch - what is wrong with this url?

Tags: elasticsearch, request

I have this url **node4:9200/search/all/_search**. But it returns empty result. 
Can somebody tell me please what is wrong with that? I did migration from Elasticsearch 2 to Elasticsearch 6 and some requests like this one stop working.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to return documents from all the indexes in your ES, it would be node4:9200/_all/_search.  For a specific index, replace '_all' with your index name.